# Can't connect metamask mobile to DApp

Tags: metamask, mobile-wallet

This code works fine on desktops but not at all on mobile.

All relevant modules imported and variables defined

```
            if(window.ethereum)
                {   web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
                    accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
                    currentAccount = accounts[0]

                }
            else if(window.web3)
                {
                    web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
                    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
                    currentAccount = accounts[0]

                }
```

Edit
I am using Chrome Android on Android 9
Using metamask Android V3.8.0
Metamask is working properly for other sites but not for my dapp.

Comment: What mobile browser are you testing with?

Comment: I am using Chrome Android. I could connect with other dapps on mobile, so metamask is working but not for my app

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this and also I added deeplinking to work with IOS and Android, it's a short code that you can see here :

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/MetaMask-React-sample

Also, it has other features like listening for changing wallet address, changing network, etc.